# how to use rapidxml get all string inside <node />

Tags: c++, rapidxml

if I have xml content as below

```
<node>
   <content> hello <b>world</b>
          <image src="src/image.jpg"/>    
   </content>    
</node>
```

I would like to get value as string which have all data inside 
or let say

```
string all_data = node->get_XXXX????();
```

Finally all_data =="< content > hello < b >world < /b > \n < image src=\"src/image.jpg\"/>\n  < /content > "

Answer (score 0):

You need to `print` it using functions in `rapidxml_print.hpp`

See here. http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1printing

```
// Print to string using output iterator
std::string s;
print(std::back_inserter(s), node, 0);
```

Be aware that this will potentially reformat whitespace, etc around tags. If that's critical to you, you should find a different way of encoding your document.